# How do I pull an unevaluated formula from one cell and evaluate it in another?

Tags: excel

I am working on making a formula in excel, and I would like to easily read and modify the formula. However, I still want the formula evaluated.

So far, I have been recreating the formula in a separate cell and evaluating it there. This exposes my work to typos, or forgetfulness, etc. and generally wastes time. I want to automate the process. 
My first attempt was to enter the formula (say: a2+b2) in one cell (c2) and simply have a second cell read=c2. However, this just makes the second cell say "a2+b2" and not evaluate.

How can I command this second cell to utilize the formula defined in the first?

Comment: Look into `indirect()`?

Comment: indirect() does not seem to work with formulas.

Answer (score 1):

First place this **U**ser **D**efined **F**unction *(UDF)* in a standard module:

```
Public Function eval(strng As String) As Variant
   eval = Evaluate(strng)
End Function
```

then pick a cell and enter:

```
=eval(C2)
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=eval(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! I would upvote you, but Stackexchange thinks I'm too noobish to do so.

Comment: @user5659766  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Without VBA:

Define Name say `EvaC2` with Refers to:

```
=EVALUATE(Sheet1!$C$2)
```

(adjust sheet name to suit), OK  then enter:

```
=EvaC2
```

Note this use XLM whose remaining lifespan is probably short.